# -bash: alias: /Users/username/.bash_profile”: not found

Tags: bash, alias

I'm trying to add some aliases to my bash profile, but it's not working for some reason and I get these errors when I open a new terminal or execute bash profile with `. ~/.bash_profile`.

---

These are the errors I get:

```
-bash: alias: /Users/username/.bash_profile”: not found 

-bash: alias: package: not found
```

---

This is what I have in my bashprofile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home

"#" Aliases

alias edit=“open ~/.bash_profile”

alias pack=“mvn package && clear”
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using fancy quotes (`“`) rather than regular quotes (`"`). This causes `~/.bash_profile”` and  `package` to appear as distinct arguments to `alias` instead of the right-hand side being taken as a single string. `alias` then starts looking for aliases with those names.

Correct the quotes and you should be all set.